# Create and store objects for JSON serialization?

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

I'm creating objects based on search results I get. I'm then trying to serialize the objects to return a JSON formatted string. I'm trying to accomplish the below scenario. I don't want to hard-code any JSON, I want the JSON to be output just from the object serialization. I'm not sure how to accomplish what I'm looking for. Note I have some user values hard-coded in my example code for simplicity's sake.

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getSearchResultsString();
    }

    public void getSearchResultsString()
    {
        string[] userList = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };

        var json = "";

        List<string> users = new List<string>();

        foreach (string user in userList)
        {

            string userName = "jsmith";

            string email = "jsmith@example.com";

            string createdDate = "3/20/2016";

            ADUser aduser = new ADUser(userName, email, createdDate);

            users.Add(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(aduser));
        }
        json = String.Join(", ", users);
        Response.Write(json);
    }

    public class ADUser
    {
        public ADUser(string UserName, string Email, string CreatedDate)
        {
            userName = UserName;
            email = Email;
            createdDate = CreatedDate;
        }

        // Properties.
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string createdDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My current output:**

```
{"userName":"jsmith","email":"jsmith@example.com","createdDate":"3/20/2016"}, {"userName":"jsmith","email":"jsmith@example.com","createdDate":"3/20/2016"}, {"userName":"jsmith","email":"jsmith@example.com","createdDate":"3/20/2016"}
```

**My desired output:**

```
{
    "users": [{
        "userName": "jsmith",
        "email": "jsmith@example.com",
        "createdDate": "3/20/2016"
    }, {
        "userName": "jsmith",
        "email": "jsmith@example.com",
        "createdDate": "3/20/2016"
    }, {
        "userName": "jsmith",
        "email": "jsmith@example.com",
        "createdDate": "3/20/2016"
    }]
}
```

Comment: don't make a list of strings, make a list of an object!

Comment: What do I need to modify/add in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to revise getSearchResultsString() as blow

```
public static void getSearchResultsString()
    {
        string[] userList = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };

        var json = "";

        List<ADUser> users = new List<ADUser>();

        foreach (string user in userList)
        {

            string userName = "jsmith";

            string email = "jsmith@example.com";

            string createdDate = "3/20/2016";

            ADUser aduser = new ADUser(userName, email, createdDate);

            users.Add(aduser);
        }
        json = new JavaScriptSerializer().
            Serialize(new { users = users });
        Response.Write(json);
    }
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! So what does the syntax 'Serialize(new { users = users });' do essentially?

Comment: I write like this to simplify the code, it just creates an Anonymous Type, for more information, you can have access to [Anonymous Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)